Universal Deep Linking Must be perform as firebase deep linking How?
Universal Deep Linking Must be perform as firebase deep linking How?
If app is installed in device direct open app if not then redirect to app store or play store
const universalLink = 'https://nextlevel.codeoptimalsolutions.com';
        // const appStoreLink = 'https://apps.apple.com/in/app/instagram/id389801252';  // Replace with your App Store link
        const appStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yourlinkexperience.android&hl=en";
        const fallbackPage = 'https://nextlevel.codeoptimalsolutions.com/login'; // Replace with your fallback page
      
        const html = `
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Launching App...</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              // Attempt to open the app using the universal link
              window.location.href = "${universalLink}";
      
              // If the app doesn't open, redirect to the fallback page after a delay
              setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "${appStoreLink}";  // Fallback to App Store or your fallback page
              }, 3000);  // 3-second delay before redirecting
            </script>
          </body>
          </html>
        `;
        res.send(html);

This code work fine when app is installed but when app is not installed code not redirecting on stores
Expecting
If app is installed in device direct open app if not then redirect to app store or play store
